model is undefined when using defineModel in defineComponent
All the examples of using defineModel are with <script setup>. What if I want to use defineModel inside defineComponent?
It seems to be possible, but I'm struggling with setting the default model value. When I try this,
in parent component:
<Child v-model="foo" /> (foo is "1")

in child component:
<script>
import { defineComponent, defineModel } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
 setup(props, ctx) {
 const model1 = defineModel()
 console.log(model1) // returns "undefined" here and when used in template

 console.log(ctx.attrs.modelValue) // returns "1"
 const model2 = defineModel({ type: String, default: ctx.attrs.modelValue })
 console.log(model2) // returns "undefined" here and when used in template

 return { model1, model2 }
 }
})
</script>

I tried two approaches (model1 and model2) but both don't work.
Why is model1 and model2 not picking up the default value from the modelValue fallthrough attribute (passed from parent to child with v-model="foo")? I'm on Vue v.3.4.23.

defineModel is a macro, it's not supposed to be used in <script>, it's a no-op there and will result in a warning:

defineModel() is a compiler-hint helper that is only usable inside <script setup> of a single file component. Its arguments should be compiled away and passing it at runtime has no effect.

In order for v-model to work, a component should declare modelValue prop, this couldn't be done by using defineModel as regular function in setup().
As the documentation states:

Under the hood, this macro declares a model prop and a corresponding value update event. <...> you can also pass an additional object which can include the prop's options and the model ref's value transform options.

